# Suggestions for a Monotouch model dialog (accessible from UITable) with text input

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitableview

I'm looking for a configurable modal dialog to popup over the top when a cell is clicked in a UITableView with various actions, some of which require input, some don't. Is Monotouch.dialog appropriate or is there a better way to achieve this?

The behaviour I'm looking for with the dialog (activated in the UITable) is the following: 
- Fixed actions. Click a button, do something. 
- Text input. Enter text (for example, reset a password), do something.

Alternatively, is it possible to use a custom controller such as QuickDialog https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog?

Sincerely,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

Popover for user-input is quite a common task. I would recommend UIPopoverController with custom views inside that when presented allow the user to complete an action / task / input. Quick dialog is a rendition of MonoTouch.Dialog ported to obj-C. You can use straight-up MonoTouch.Dialog if you like: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

I would also recommend my managed C# implementation of UIPopover for MonoTouch here (with video): https://github.com/anujb/Devnos.Popover

Video: http://screencast.com/t/lGwsvtEot9V

[image: Video of Popover for MonoTouch]